# What make us believe in Jesus?

Tags: bible, faith

There is no proof that the Bible comes from God but we still believe in Jesus Christ .I think that nobody was there when the Bible was been writing but how can we believe ? It is not logical for me ?What is the mystery behind this ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Unfortunately your question is really too broad - there are so many reasons that lead people to believe in Jesus, and each person has different reasons that matter more to them. But I hope you'll stick around here to ask and answer many more questions! Please read the [tour] if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct:
God isn't real.
It is all illogical.
What Jesus is supposed to have done is crazy.

Unless... God opens the mind to know that He is.

No one can find God - they simply make up their own god as it seems man has a need for some higher power or wisdom - that's why there are so many religions.

This is not the age for all to know and believe in God and what He sent Jesus to do. The Israelites didn't choose God - He chose them. Today, God still 'chooses' those to know Him and others will just have to wait their turn. Or, ask in prayer and God may answer to reveal Himself to them.

These things are spiritually understood, and man does not have God's spirit until He gives it to them.

Comment: "For **what can be known about God is plain to them, because God has shown it to them**. For his invisible attributes, namely, his eternal power and divine nature, **have been clearly perceived**, ever since the creation of the world, in the things that have been made. So they are without excuse. **For although they knew God**, they did not honor him as God or give thanks to him, but they became futile in their thinking, and their foolish hearts were darkened."  -  Active rebellion is the issue not ignorance.

Comment: @MikeBorden Surely you must consider Adam and Eve similarly - they walked with God, but they fell victim to deception. And all since are born into such deception. That they are 'without excuse' does not relieve them of being deceived until God does so in each. The evidence is all the more then pointing to how vast and encompassing the deception was! It was constantly before them - but they saw it not, nor the One who created.

Comment: "For although they knew God, they did not honor him as God or give thanks to him, but they became futile in their thinking, and their foolish hearts were darkened."  I think that sums up Adam and Eve pretty nicely.   Does the deception consist of not being able to find God or to know that HE IS or is it an increasing belief that we do not need Him to define good and evil for us (futile thinking)?  The sheep that don't hear Jesus' voice...is it because they cannot or will not?  Isaiah 30:15, John 5:39-40

Comment: True. How does one recover from “ they became futile in their thinking, and their foolish hearts were darkened” ? Only God can turn this around. Much like he did with Paul, though this is an extreme example, but the results will be the same for all others. Therefore, Cannot

Comment: Pushed all the way to it's limit, *cannot* brings us either to universalism or makes 2 Peter 3:9 untrue.  Only God can turn this around - absolutely!  And He has.  The gospel **is** the power of God unto salvation for those believing.  Why would Paul bother trying to persuade men if *cannot* were the default state?  But *cannot* is tied into a lack of preaching and hearing and believing and calling on Him (Romans 10:14-17).